# Spring Security authentication context propagation

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring Security 3 claims to provide a transparent authentication context propagation for HttpInvoker.

Can anyone point me to the exact location for this integration code (I've looked though Spring Security code itself and find nothing, as well as in the HttpInvoker related classes)?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I got it up to now, based on: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence:

> The server caches the principal information for the duration session. In Spring Security, the responsibility for storing the SecurityContext between requests falls to the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, which by default stores the context as an HttpSession attribute between HTTP requests.

you should check:  `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`

On the other hand, I have experience with Spring 2.5.x only and it was achievable using:
`HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter` ( http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/context/HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.html )

Moreover on the client side you should make sure that you use some session propagation implementation between calls, usually `CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor` ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.html ).